# Azure data factory sftp

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have copied the file from an sFTP loc which is a zip file and in zip, I have CSV format but when the file came to azure blob but the file extension came as .zip.txt can someone suggest how this is happening and how can I get CSV as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the "compression type" option?

[image]

[image]

This will work for legacy zip. If the zip is with AES encryption or with a password,  you will need a custom activity and do the unzipping using an Azure function with some code inside.

Comment: previously when I'm doing this I did not select the Binary in the sink so it by default taken the file type as txt. Now I have selected Binary so I got my desired zip file to Azure.